# React even set static defaultProps, but error why?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What I've known is when you use typescript 3.x above you can use `static defaultProps = {...}` 
in order to use Component without injecting props which is defaultProps.

So I tried it in my project, but an error occurs `Property 'mod' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Pick<ResultsInputPanelProps, "mod">'.  TS2741` why is it????

```
//in ResultsInputPanel .tsx
export type Mod = "create" | "update" | "read";

interface ResultsInputPanelProps extends WithTranslation, DefaultProps {}

interface DefaultProps {
  mod: Mod;
}

interface ResultsInputPanelStates {
  patientInfo: PatientInfo;
  inputValues: any;
}

class ResultsInputPanel extends React.Component<ResultsInputPanelProps, ResultsInputPanelStates> {
  static defaultProps: DefaultProps = { mod: "create" };

  //...
}

export default withTranslation(COG_TEST_PAGE)(ResultsInputPanel);

// another page.tsx
//...
   {tabIndex === 0 ? <ResultsInputPanel /> : <div />}
// ...
```

```
export function withTranslation(
  ns?: Namespace,
  options?: {
    withRef?: boolean;
  }
): <P extends WithTranslation>(
  component: React.ComponentType<P>,
) => React.ComponentType<Omit<P, keyof WithTranslation>>;
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "typescript": "3.4.5",
     //...
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a default value to a prop, you need to define it as an optional property to the component, so you have to mark the `DefaultProps` as a `Partial` type:

```
interface ResultsInputPanelProps extends WithTranslation, Partial<DefaultProps> {}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my investigation it is because of `withTranslation` of **react-i18next**

See: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/736